# Return makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Tags: pointers, integer

> I get the following error on Code execution. What am i missing?
>       warning: passing argument 1 of ‘Max’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>       warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion].

//Header files declaration

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//Function Declarations

int Max(int Ar[15],int x);
int Array(int Ar[15],int a);


int main()
{
    int Ary[15],x1,Max1;

  printf("\n \n Enter the Size of Array: ");
  scanf("%d",&x1);

  printf(" Input elements of Array:");  


   //Function Call

   //Array Builder
   Array(Ary[15], x1);

   //Compute Maximum Number of Array
  Max1=Max(Ary[15],x1);

   //Displaying Maximum Number of Array

   printf("\n Maximum Number of Array:");
   printf("%d",Max1);         

   return 0;
 }

//Function-Build Array    

int Array(int Ar[15],int a)
{
 int i,j;
 for(i=0;i<a;i++)
 {
  scanf("%d",&Ar[i]);
 }
 return Ar;
}
```

//Function-Compute Maximum element of Array

```
int Max(int Ar[15],int x)
{
    int i,j,v,Max_n;
    Ar[0]=Max_n;

    for(i=1;i<x;i++)
 {
   if(Ar[i]>Max_n)    
   {
      v=Max_n;
      Max_n=Ar[i];
      Ar[i]=v;

   }
 }
 return Max_n;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ary[15] gives you the last int of your array, you should try to pass the array itself instead : Array(Ary,x1) and Max(Ary,x1).

By the way, it was only a warning. A big one though, your program is bound to crash at some point.

Comment: I want to return the Maximum Number from int Max function to main program.But unfortunately i am getting a long number like 45867859 when i call Max Number through function call  Max1=Max(Ary,x1); How to avoid this? What am i to do if have to get the exact  integer ?

Comment: First, please tell us more details about how you are doing it.
I can't tell anything about what should or should not work based on your comment only.
My guess is, if you get a huge number like this, either you forgot to initialize the array, or worse, you're going after it's last entry (Ar[14]) so you picked up any value that was stored right after the array.